# Checking boolean in all class instances

Tags: python

I have a list of objects in a simulation which are are moving around a space in a synchronised manner. To achieve this I've created a class with a Boolean value to which is set to true once the object has reached its destination, and is waiting for every object to be finished so they can all start the next leg together.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, ID):
        self.ID = ID
        self.finished_condition = False

    def time_evolution(self, time_step):
        # Some method that updates the class instance over time, 

    def complete_check(self):
        # If the object is approximately at its finish point, as error
        # is allowed in position - set self.finished_condition to True

    def start_next_movement(self):
        # Some method called to begin the next leg:
        # called when all instances are finished.

object_list = [MyClass('1'), MyClass('2'), MyClass('3')]

while simulation_running == True:
    for k in object_list:
        k.time_evolution(0.05)
        k.complete_check()

    # If all finished_condition == True then call start_next_movement
    # for all instances of MyClass.
```

I've formed these into a list of class instances, and I want to check whether all of the objects have finished their previous movement step so I can begin the next one. Clearly I can check whether 'finished_condition' is true inside a loop, but I'm wondering if there is a neater way of doing it.

Is there an easy way of checking whether this Boolean is true/false for every instance of this class?

Comment: What is wrong with the loop?

Comment: `all(o.finished_condition for o in object_list)`

Comment: Daaaayum, @ŁukaszRogalski. Could you be quicker? XD

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski is it that simple? Obviously I'm being pretty thick this morning...

Answer (score 0):

Given `object_list = [MyClass('1'), MyClass('2'), MyClass('3')]`,

check in a loop like `all(o.finished_condition for o in object_list)` as pointed out by @Łukasz, or by overloading:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, id_):
        self._id = id_
        self._finished_condition = False

    def __nonzero__(self):  # legacy Python2
        return self._finished_condition

    def __bool__(self):     # Python3
        return self._finished_condition
```

Then: `all(object_list)`.

Comment: I don't know whether overriding the `__bool__` is advisable here: one frequently writes `if object:` now here an object will only have truthiness `True` if is moving which does not feel very "correct".

Comment: That is a valid argument. However, usefulness highly depends on the use-case. In the described simple/custom scenario, I would use the feature. I am not aware of a generalized "`__bool__` considered harmful".. whereas [Null / None](http://wiki.c2.com/?NullConsideredHarmful) is.

Comment: no, of course not. But for instance the thrutiness of a list is whether it contains at least one element. That seems to make sense. The fact that an object that is not moving is False, is something different.

Comment: So this is about readability, right? Then an `all(map(is_finished, object_list))` (or similar) might be easier to understand, yes.